# rendering d3-timeseries on d3-plunker

Tags: javascript, d3.js, plunker

I'm in need to use d3-timeseries graph given on link:
http://mcaule.github.io/d3-timeseries/

I'm having some JSON data which I will use to plot on this graph. I'm trying to make this work on d3 plunker.

Being new to D3 and plunker,I'm not sure if I'm doing the code at right places or not as nothing is coming up. Please guide me.

Code I'm trying to use on d3-plunker:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>
var data : [{date:new Date('2013-01-01'),n:120,n3:124,ci_up:130,ci_down:118},
            {date:new Date('2013-01-02'),n:121,n3:124,ci_up:130,ci_down:118},
            {date:new Date('2013-01-03'),n:122,n3:124,ci_up:130,ci_down:118},
            {date:new Date('2013-01-04'),n:123,n3:124,ci_up:130,ci_down:118},
            {date:new Date('2013-01-05'),n:124,n3:124,ci_up:130,ci_down:118},
            {date:new Date('2013-01-06'),n:125,n3:124,ci_up:130,ci_down:118},
            {date:new Date('2013-01-07'),n:126,n3:124,ci_up:130,ci_down:118},
            {date:new Date('2013-01-08'),n:127,n3:124,ci_up:130,ci_down:118},
            {date:new Date('2013-01-09'),n:128,n3:124,ci_up:130,ci_down:118},
            {date:new Date('2013-01-10'),n:129,n3:124,ci_up:130,ci_down:118}]
var chart = d3.timeseries()
          .addSerie(data.slice(0,60),{x:'date',y:'n'},{interpolate:'linear',color:"#a6cee3",label:"value"})
          .addSerie(data.slice(50),
              {x:'date',y:'n3',ci_up:'ci_up',ci_down:'ci_down'},
              {interpolate:'monotone',dashed:true,color:"#a6cee3",label:"prediction"})
          .width(900)

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have to reference d3-timeseries:

```
<script src="https://mcaule.github.io/d3-timeseries/src/d3_timeseries.js"></script>
```

After that, at the end of your code, you have to call it:

```
chart("body")
```

Finally, have in mind that this is not a valid JavaScript:

```
var data : [];
```

It should be `var data = []` instead.

Here is your working code (click "run code snippet"):

```js
var data = [{
  date: new Date('2013-01-01'),
  n: 120,
  n3: 124,
  ci_up: 130,
  ci_down: 118
}, {
  date: new Date('2013-01-02'),
  n: 121,
  n3: 124,
  ci_up: 130,
  ci_down: 118
}, {
  date: new Date('2013-01-03'),
  n: 122,
  n3: 124,
  ci_up: 130,
  ci_down: 118
}, {
  date: new Date('2013-01-04'),
  n: 123,
  n3: 124,
  ci_up: 130,
  ci_down: 118
}, {
  date: new Date('2013-01-05'),
  n: 124,
  n3: 124,
  ci_up: 130,
  ci_down: 118
}, {
  date: new Date('2013-01-06'),
  n: 125,
  n3: 124,
  ci_up: 130,
  ci_down: 118
}, {
  date: new Date('2013-01-07'),
  n: 126,
  n3: 124,
  ci_up: 130,
  ci_down: 118
}, {
  date: new Date('2013-01-08'),
  n: 127,
  n3: 124,
  ci_up: 130,
  ci_down: 118
}, {
  date: new Date('2013-01-09'),
  n: 128,
  n3: 124,
  ci_up: 130,
  ci_down: 118
}, {
  date: new Date('2013-01-10'),
  n: 129,
  n3: 124,
  ci_up: 130,
  ci_down: 118
}]
var chart = d3.timeseries()
  .addSerie(data.slice(0, 60), {
    x: 'date',
    y: 'n'
  }, {
    interpolate: 'linear',
    color: "#a6cee3",
    label: "value"
  })
  .addSerie(data.slice(50), {
    x: 'date',
    y: 'n3',
    ci_up: 'ci_up',
    ci_down: 'ci_down'
  }, {
    interpolate: 'monotone',
    dashed: true,
    color: "#a6cee3",
    label: "prediction"
  })
  .width(900)

chart("body")
```

```css
.axis line, .axis path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://mcaule.github.io/d3-timeseries/src/d3_timeseries.js"></script>
```

Comment: In a external file or in a `<style>` element: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Comment: No, I won't: you didn't even say "thanks", and now you're making a different question. I'm not your personal consultant.

Comment: ohh I'm sorry. Thanks. I completely forgot as I'm too much puzzled with this thing.Can you check now if possible?

Comment: No worries. Since you have a different problem regarding your data structure, please post a new question. In the new question, copy my working snippet (it's a symbol like this: <>), so users can see the code working and address only the data structure problem.

Comment: can you look this question now? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44664859/how-to-render-d3-timeseries-graph-with-json