# how to render d3-timeseries graph with json

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

Render D3-timeseries graph using customized json.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://mcaule.github.io/d3-timeseries/src/d3_timeseries.js"></script>
<script>
var data = [{
  date: new Date('2013-01-01'),
  n: 120,
  n3: 124,
  ci_up: 130,
  ci_down: 118
}, {
  date: new Date('2013-01-02'),
  n: 121,
  n3: 124,
  ci_up: 130,
  ci_down: 118
}, {
  date: new Date('2013-01-03'),
  n: 122,
  n3: 124,
  ci_up: 130,
  ci_down: 118
}, {
  date: new Date('2013-01-04'),
  n: 123,
  n3: 124,
  ci_up: 130,
  ci_down: 118
}, {
  date: new Date('2013-01-05'),
  n: 124,
  n3: 124,
  ci_up: 130,
  ci_down: 118
}, {
  date: new Date('2013-01-06'),
  n: 125,
  n3: 124,
  ci_up: 130,
  ci_down: 118
}, {
  date: new Date('2013-01-07'),
  n: 126,
  n3: 124,
  ci_up: 130,
  ci_down: 118
}, {
  date: new Date('2013-01-08'),
  n: 127,
  n3: 124,
  ci_up: 130,
  ci_down: 118
}, {
  date: new Date('2013-01-09'),
  n: 128,
  n3: 124,
  ci_up: 130,
  ci_down: 118
}, {
  date: new Date('2013-01-10'),
  n: 129,
  n3: 124,
  ci_up: 130,
  ci_down: 118
}]
var chart = d3.timeseries()
  .addSerie(data.slice(0, 60), {
    x: 'date',
    y: 'n'
  }, {
    interpolate: 'linear',
    color: "#a6cee3",
    label: "value"
  })
  .addSerie(data.slice(50), {
    x: 'date',
    y: 'n3',
    ci_up: 'ci_up',
    ci_down: 'ci_down'
  }, {
    interpolate: 'monotone',
    dashed: true,
    color: "#a6cee3",
    label: "prediction"
  })
  .width(900)
chart("body")

</script>
```

above code is working fine. But I do not want to use above json, in that json labels X:date and Y:n can be easily specified in code. If my json is in below format, how do i specify labels?

```
var data = [{
    "2017-06-18 20:00:00": {
      "y0": {
        "abc": [
          "19.009346319350104",
          "18.86377513528457",
          "19.14897759084037"
        ],
        "def": [
          "19.006583977261155",
          "18.859021107208214",
          "19.146434493881344"
        ]
      },
      "y1": {
        "abc": [
          "19.606573982955613",
          "19.542083239833666",
          "19.670561738263423"
        ],
        "def": [
          "19.60606089511234",
          "19.543457128306787",
          "19.669551590667393"
        ]
      }
    },
    "2017-06-18 21:00:00": {
      "y0": {
        "abc": [
          "19.012427351469185",
          "18.859120342583186",
          "19.151724224708172"
        ],
        "def": [
          "19.010479324266342",
          "18.862248149777905",
          "19.149184304624885"
        ]
      },
      "y1": {
        "abc": [
          "19.610420374515755",
          "19.55086449476118",
          "19.672216154191055"
        ],
        "def": [
          "19.61016448534518",
          "19.54595086235455",
          "19.672144443443653"
        ]
      }
    },
    "2017-06-18 22:00:00": {
      "y0": {
        "abc": [
          "19.01550838358827",
          "18.871871993054704",
          "19.162290269570583"
        ],
        "def": [
          "19.014374671271526",
          "18.861438145035137",
          "19.1620368795241"
        ]
      },
      "y1": {
        "abc": [
          "19.614266766075897",
          "19.54791169277493",
          "19.68136057710245"
        ],
        "def": [
          "19.61426807557802",
          "19.55267636120965",
          "19.681166682649557"
        ]
      }
    }]
```

here, x should be time, y should y0[abc][0] ,ci_down should be  y0[abc][1],ci_up should be y0[abc][2]. Please suggest if that's possible or not.